# How to pass animate:flip to a component in svelte?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component, svelte-transition

I'm trying to animate this list of Widgets. Of course I can't just `animate:flip` a component, Svelte needs a DOM element.

```
<!-- invalid -->
{#each widgets as widget (widget.id)}
    <Widget {...widget} animate:flip/>
{/each}
```

I normally would have solved it with a simple container div:

```
<!-- does not apply to my situation -->
{#each widgets as widget (widget.id)}
  <div animate:flip>
    <Widget {...widget} />
  </div>
{/each}
```

However, as I'm using a CSS Grid around the `#each`, I need Widget to be the immediate child. I can't wrap it in anything. How can I solve this? Is there any way to pass `animate:flip` to the Widget component and handling it there?

Here is [a REPL of what I'm trying to achieve](https://svelte.dev/repl/3386549a0e7f4488b6b8113c8b9874d6?version=3.44.1). I'm unable to get the same behaviour when each row (containing three cells) is a Component.

Comment: How's the html structure inside the Widget? Maybe you could make a small [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.44.1) ?

Comment: This is an [example](https://svelte.dev/repl/dbd68e3fe7ee4a38818eeb1aef42e644?version=3.44.1) with a grid containing a Component. What's different in your case that the wrapper div with animate on it, is not possible?

Comment: @Corrl Thank you for looking into this! I've adapted your example to my situation: https://svelte.dev/repl/4707e7f2469e42ac80771d1314b51e49?version=3.44.1 . Here, wrapping the Component breaks the CSS grid.

Comment: Since you're basically trying to animate rows, you'll have to split your grid into two components: an outer grid of 1 column and *n* rows, and for each row, the same inner grid of *p* columns applied. Like this: https://svelte.dev/repl/d0a93034de2c4c27b3f1beb313427c1a?version=3.44.1

Comment: If your question is how to do this without the intermediate wrapper div, this answer is you cannot, because a grid row is not a document node.

Comment: @ThomasHennes Thank you for helping! The issue with introducing a nested grid seems to be that the cell widths need to be specified, as in the case with your REPL. The cells no longer adapt their widths, as they do in [the REPL I posted](svelte.dev/repl/4707e7f2469e42ac80771d1314b51e49?version=3.44.1). Do you think this is impossible to achieve if I want *both* CSS Grid and `flip:animate`, and I should be looking for another CSS layout solution?

Comment: "cell widths need to be specified, as in the case with your REPL" - you mean because they are set to '1fr 1fr 1fr' instead of 'auto auto auto'? " The cells no longer adapt their widths"  - I can't see that, could you describe why you mean that?

Comment: @Corrl I've written a new REPL without Components that shows the behaviour I'm trying to achieve. I'm unable to achieve it *with* a Component representing each row (three cells): https://svelte.dev/repl/3386549a0e7f4488b6b8113c8b9874d6?version=3.44.1

Comment: Thanks Anna, just got what you mean! I'll have a look...

Comment: @Corrl I added `auto auto auto` and some zeroes and get this behaviour on your REPL: https://imgur.com/a/KZKVpJ0 whereas I'm looking for this alignment: https://imgur.com/a/M5Va5vL

Comment: Since you're looking for a 'table-like' behaviour, using this instead of grid might be a solution? Have a look at [this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c648b71dc42f4e059abee999e351ff17?version=3.44.1) using "display: table/table-row/table-cell" (using table/tr/td elements might work as well)

Comment: In fact I moved away from table to CSS grid for some styling requirements that are no longer needed in this project, so I think this might be a good solution for my case! Thank you @Corrl !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aditionally to the

##### first solution  >>  table

Which was to use either `<table>, <tr>, <td>` or `<div>`s with `display: table, table-row, table-cell` to preserve the auto-width-adjustments of the columns -> [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c648b71dc42f4e059abee999e351ff17?version=3.44.1)

I just had an idea for a

##### second solution  >>  subgrid

which is unfortunately **only supported in Firefox 71+** [(caniuse.com)](https://caniuse.com/?search=subgrid) at the moment, but might be worth knowing for the future anyway when it (hopefully!! ) have wide browser support eventually

With that you could have kept your original structure, with these adjustments:

- add the wrapper-div for the 'row component'
- style it with

```css
display: grid;
grid-column: 1/-1;
grid-template-columns: subgrid;
```

and you're done :-)

This [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/5cb9d070c24e4e13a865526246978ad5?version=3.44.1) illustrates the solution, **when opened in firefox 71+**

Comment: Neither of these worked for me. The component being looped through are inside a grid, so adding the CSS mentioned above in any combination doesn't work.

Comment: My element had `inline-block` which is why the grid styles were messing with it. Removing that was the solution for me. Man that took a few hours...

Answer (score 0):

Idea 1:
apply `display: contents` to the container div.

Idea 2:
Obvious but maybe you can add `animate:flip` to the `Widget` component, maybe conditionally with a prop.

Comment: 'display: contents' sounds like a good idea, but unfortunately it seems to break the animate - just tried it in this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/dbd68e3fe7ee4a38818eeb1aef42e644?version=3.44.1)

Comment: Thank you Zachiah. Idea 1 seems not to work. Could you please explain what you mean by idea 2?

Comment: What is inside the widget component? Could you just put `animate:flip` inside it?

Comment: @Zachiah I made a REPL here to show the example: svelte.dev/repl/4707e7f2469e42ac80771d1314b51e49?version=3.44.1 It's the lower grid that I'm trying to animate.